# How to transition page scrolling using Polymer's neon elements

Tags: html, css, animation, polymer

I am new to Polymer. I'm trying to explore the animation resources through the Polymer neon-* elements.

Based on demos in Polymer Project, I found how to transition between pages:

```
<neon-animated-pages id="pages" class="flex" selected="{{selected}}"  entry-animation="slide-from-left-animation" exit-animation="slide-right-animation">
   <neon-animatable>
      <h1>Consultoria</h1>
   </neon-animatable>
   <neon-animatable>
      <h1>Treinamento</h1>
   </neon-animatable>
   <neon-animatable>
      <h1>Institucional</h1>
   </neon-animatable>
```

This works great!

But, I would like to explore various forms of transition and animation in a single page, only using Polymer Elements, similar to the Inbox Google homepage:

http://www.google.com/inbox/

My initial question:
How the scroll transitions of sections tags could be implemented

```
<section> </section>
```

using Polymer neon- * elements , similar to Google Inbox behavior?

Thank you for any contribution!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do it easily with polymer only because they have iron-pages and neon-animated-pages for sections switching and neither supports natively one page scrolling.

I was looking similar example as google inbox, in the end I created it with the help of iscroll.js.

It also looks and works very good because you there are no scroll bars in any browser, iscroll uses css transition.

https://github.com/sgoran/polymer-spa